# 95% CI or standard error of predicted risk in Cox regression using R

Tags: multiple-regression, predictive-models, cox-model

I am doing a multivariate Cox regression. I got the predicted risk for a new scenario based on the existing Cox model in R using function `predictSurvProb` in the `pec` package.

Now I want to figure out the 95% CI of this predicted risk. How can I do it?

Here are my codes:

```
# fit a Cox model
f.coxph <- coxph(Surv(recurtime, recurrence) ~ age + pgs.f + svi.f + ece.f 
           +  margin.f, data=prostate) 
# predicted 5-year recurrence risk for a 55-year old, pathological Gleason score 6, 
# positive surgical margin, negative SVI, and negative ECE
case1 <- data.frame(age=55, pgs.f="GS 5-6", margin.f="Pos", 
         svi.f="Neg", ece.f="Neg")
predictSurvProb(f.coxph, newdata=case1, times=60)
```

Or how to calculate the standard error of this predicted recurrence risk? So I can use `fit+/-1.96*se.fit` to get the 95% CI.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure about `predictSurvProb` but you can do this with similar commands using the R `rms` package; see its `survest` function.